# Get path to function declaration in javascript

Tags: javascript

For example, given

```
// foo.js
function bar() {
    ...
}
```

How can I implement a function such as

```
function getPathOf(func) {
    return ...
}
console.log(getPathOf(foo.bar)) // Prints: "foo.js:1:1"
```

That is to say, how can I get the source file path, line number, and column number of a given function.

I know Function.name gives the name of a function, and I have seen assertion libraries such as chai.js print the path to a function when printing a stack trace.

Comment: Unless there is a way to make the function throw an error that you can then use to get the filepath, I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only expression that exposes the current line number and file is `new Error` :

```
 console.log((new Error()).stack);
```

thats how the libraries generate stacktraces, there is no other way to get it.

---

I guess something like:

```
 fs.readFileSync("foo.js").indexOf(func.toString())
```

might work somehow but thats just ugly and serves no real purpose.